# How to virtualize a FlatList inside FlatList (RN Web)?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-web, flatlist

How do I convince a vertical [React Native FlatList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist) to virtualize correctly inside another vertical (non-virtualizing) FlatList, in React Native Web?

So far, it seems that by default, scrolling to a certain point or responsive resize re-renderings tend to cause the virtualization to go haywire.  [This Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@drieman/nested-flatlist-breaks-virtualization) demonstrates the problem.  Be sure you're on the "Web" tab as the device builds seem to work correctly.  Here's a repro [through codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/skycve) too.

**Update**: Per request, here's the code inline as well.  This is a full program that can paste into, say, a new `expo init` project (or similar) to see the strange behavior and experiment with it.

```js
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
import { FlatList, Text, useWindowDimensions, View } from 'react-native';

// Make 200 rows for the big list (which will draw green and red with some info).
const bigListData = Array(200).fill(0).map((element, index) => index);

function onViewableChange({ viewableItems }) {
  if (viewableItems.length < 2) {
    console.log(`VIEWABLE CHANGE! Only ${viewableItems.length} visible...`);
  } else {
    console.log(`VIEWABLE CHANGE! ${viewableItems[0].index} to ${viewableItems[viewableItems.length - 1].index}`);
  }
}

function BigList() {
  const { height, width } = useWindowDimensions();
  const betweenRows = 10;
  const itemHeight = height / 8;
  const totalRowHeight = itemHeight + betweenRows;

  const renderer = useCallback(({ item }) => {
    const key = `i_${item}`;
    return <View key={key} style={{
                 backgroundColor: item % 2 ? "red" : "green",
                 height: itemHeight,
                 width: '90%',
                 marginLeft: '5%',
                 marginBottom: betweenRows }}>
      <Text>{key}, rh: {totalRowHeight}, offset: {totalRowHeight * item}, i {item}</Text>
    </View>;
  }, [itemHeight, totalRowHeight]);

  const getItemLayout = useCallback((__data, index) => ({
    index,
    length: itemHeight,
    offset: index * totalRowHeight
  }), [itemHeight, totalRowHeight]);

  return <FlatList
    data={bigListData}
    getItemLayout={getItemLayout}
    key={'flatList'}
    numColumns={1}
    onViewableItemsChanged={onViewableChange}
    renderItem={renderer}
  />;
}

function NoNestedFlatLists() {
  const windowHeight = useWindowDimensions().height;
  return <View style={{ height: windowHeight, width: '80%' }}><BigList /></View>;
}

function renderComponent({ item }) {
  if (item.type === "widget") {
    // Using height 600 here, but assume we cannot easily predict this height (due to text wrappings).
    return <View key={item.type} style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', height: 600, width: '100%', marginBottom: 15 }} />
  }
  return <BigList key={item.type} />;
}

function NestedFlatLists() {
  const windowHeight = useWindowDimensions().height;
  const components = [{ type: "widget" }, { type: "bigList" }];

  return <FlatList
    data={components}
    key={'dynamicAppFlatList'}
    numColumns={1}
    renderItem={renderComponent}
    style={{ height: windowHeight, width: '80%' }}
    />;
}

export default function App() {
  const windowHeight = useWindowDimensions().height;
  
  // Rendering just the following has no virtualization issues.
  // The viewable change events make sense, no items suddenly disappear, no complete app meltdown...
  //return <NoNestedFlatLists />;

  // However:
  // Any useful dynamic "rows of components" architecture melts down when virtualization comes into play.
  // This sample represents such an app whose feeds have asked the app to render a "widget" followed by a
  // "bigList" who could well have a few hundred items itself and thus really needs virtualization to work
  // well on low-end devices. This demo leans on console logs. In snack.expo.dev, at time of writing, these
  // feel hidden: Click the footer bar, either on the checkmark or an empty space, and then the "Logs" tab.
  // Once you scroll down about half way in the "App", even slowly, you'll get logs like the following:
  //   Chrome: VIEWABLE CHANGE! 83 to 90
  //   Chrome: VIEWABLE CHANGE! 85 to 92
  //   Chrome: VIEWABLE CHANGE! Only 0 visible...
  //   Chrome: VIEWABLE CHANGE! 176 to 183
  //   Chrome: VIEWABLE CHANGE! 177 to 184
  // At which time, all the UI disappears. What it thinks is viewable is quite wrong. Try to scroll around,
  // but none of the mid rows are drawing. There is no easy way to repair app behavior from this state. The
  // only rows which still draw correctly during the problem are the top and bottom non-virtualizing rows.
  // 
  // As an alternate repro, you can scroll to near the middle and then resize the bottom of the window, and
  // similar virtualization problems can occur. (In our real app, we can be scrolled almost anywhere out of
  // the non-virtualizing rows, and make a 1px window resize to break the app. We have a more complex app
  // structure, but I'm hoping a fix for this snack will still be applicable to our own symptoms...)
  return <NestedFlatLists />;
}
```

Hopefully I am missing something trivial, as it seems clear React Native is *attempting* to handle nested FlatLists of the same orientation, and for the most part does great.  Until you *happen* to have enough data items to bring virtualization into play, and even then, only fails for Web.  (We've tried upgrading React Native to all the way to 0.67.2 and React Native Web to 0.17.5 - the latest releases - with no luck, and none of the Expo dropdown versions yield correct behavior in the linked Snack either.)  What can I change in either sample to have correct virtualization in the nested FlatList?

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is: You can't convince FlatList to virtualize this way correctly. At least currently (0.17), it's broken.

Although I was able to get some FlatList virtualization improvements into React Native Web's 0.18 preview, ultimately the measurement problems are deeper than I could afford to spend more weeks to fully fix. (If someone wants to try picking up from there - I recommend to focus on reconciling RNW's ScrollView versus RN's ScrollView and then digging into the ScrollView's measurements going absolutely haywire in the repro scenario, if replicating RN's evolution of ScrollView to RNW isn't enough.)

It ended up being much faster though to build our own virtualizing list component from scratch.  Ours is specialized to our needs ATM so probably won't become open source, but who knows.  But if you need to go this route... think about throttling reactions to scroll events and such to ".measure" the container view ref periodically and decide which things you need to render versus just rendering reserved empty space for... etc.  There are other approaches but that seems to work.